# On expanded usercard add a line with "last seen" status

Tags: feature-request, user-card

I believe a useful feature on the expanded usercard would be the time a user was "last seen". The time a user was "last seen" can already be found on their profile.

Currently the expanded usercard *can* look like:

[image: Current expanded user card.]

when a user has not provided a link to their website.

And as you can see, there is a void below the user's location. Why not fill it with something useful:

[image: Requested expanded user card.]

My feature request is actually slightly more general: regardless of a provided website or not, simply include the "last seen" info *somewhere* on the expanded usercard.

---

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: The void below the user's location is for their website. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/glMaC.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSfZH.png.

Comment: If you're interested, this feature is in the [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091) userscript (I am one of the developers). It looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akTAN.png, not in the usercard but just under the name instead.

Comment: @DonaldDuck First off, thank you for the examples. Maybe you had not noticed, but the post includes below the horizontal ruler (perhaps not very clearly) an example from SE/help itself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ thank you for your reply. Please excuse my ignorance, but how should I view the fact that this feature is implemented on SOX? E.g. does that mean it will become the norm? Or is SO/SE just experimenting with it?

Comment: @Jim that is just a userscript, nothing official. It was written by private people who do not work for Stack Overflow. If you don't know what userscript is, better leave it alone, as it might also cause unexpected problems so one better know how to remove it when installing it.

Comment: @Jim sorry, I should have been more clear but yes it's completely unofficial!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ It's fine, thank you anyway. It illustrates that other people found this to be a useful feature. I hope you agree.

Comment: Why is that information useful enough to be part of that dialog? tag badges relevant to the post would likely be more useful, if the goal is simply to fill a void.

Comment: @KevinB I would like to quickly be able to judge if a user (often a new user) has abandoned a question or not.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "Last seen" how about after 6 months of inactivity on all sites we have "Not seen for X months" - then we might make assumptions that they have abandoned the post and that replies (or choosing an answer) may not be forthcoming.

Comment: Some users might due to that train of thought that they rather not provide an answer to questions from users that are *Not seen for ...* which would hurt gathering quality attributions to questions that are deemed valuable by the community.

Comment: Most actions have favorable points and unfavorable ones - it's how people choose to use them. What is the value of "Last seen X hours ago"? - Does it mean they'll be back shortly, and certainly within 18 hours; I wouldn't want to bet on it. What if it says: "Last seen 4380.005 hours (6 months) ago"?, how is that different. A few clicks would obtain the answer, my suggestion was only to make more useful information more easily available. That there should be some means to choose answers for abandoned questions is a different issue; somewhat resolved by accumulated votes. Your improvement is ...

Comment: The "last seen" info is already available on a user profile. Including it on the usercard would just cause less hassle.